# Add different programmes, python code, other dockerfiles to one single dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I want to create a dockerfile out of several different programmes including other dockerfiles and python code.

It should contain the following:
connectome-workbench
FSL
FreeSurfer
Multimodal Surface Matching (MSM)
Ciftify
fmriprep-docker (also a dockerfile)
mcflirt
Different Python Scripts

Can I add every single dependency as following?

> ```
> FROM ubuntu
>
> USER root
>
> RUN apt-get update && \
> apt-get install -y curl gnupg gnupg1 gnupg2 python3-pip
>
> RUN apt-get update && \
> apt-get install -y git-annex && \
> pip install ciftify
>
> #Get the other like that as well
>
> CMD python /app/app.py
> ```

Cheers

Comment: You can add things to existing Docker images, so I would suggest starting with the [fmriprep Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nipreps/fmriprep), because it will contain many of the things you want. Then you need to figure out what software you still need to install.

Comment: The problem is when I use FROM fmriprep Docker image. It automatically starts the fmriprep process when I run the docker image I created with FROM fmriprep. But I do not want to start fmriprep but my own pipeline. FROM fmriprep probably uses the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/nipreps/fmriprep/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: To solve that, you can [set the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). Here is [part of the fmriprep dockerfile](https://github.com/nipreps/fmriprep/blob/237523c0926fd84b60d6249088c13167455e5a16/Dockerfile#L264) that sets their entrypoint.

Comment: okay good, that works now. In the end I would like to run a python script with the docker image. So, I set my ENTRYPOINT to that python script.

 This python script uses e.g. the fmriprep-docker command:
subprocess.run(['fmriprep-docker',....
But when I run the created dockerfile it does not find the fmriprep-docker or the other dependencies.

Comment: Great progress! Can you edit this question with your Dockerfile and the exact error you are getting? Along with your desired behavior.

Comment: I think it is easier to use fmriprep and not fmriprep-docker, because this is a docker wrapper. So I would have a docker wrapper in a docker container.

The new error which came up when using fmriprep in a subprocess command in python is TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
But running the command with the same datapathes directly in the terminal works fine

Comment: subprocess.run[('fmriprep', str(subject_path), str(subject_path)+'/derivatives/participant/', 'participant', '--fs-subjects-dir', str(path_freesurfer))] 
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The square brackets `[` and `]` are causing that. To call a function, you use parentheses.